# RestAssured: Can't find the equalTo method

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am using the following code for making the service call using the Rest assured library, can you help me to resolve the build issues. There is a problem in finding the function `"equalTo"` to validate the response data.

**See error below:**

[image: See error]

**Here is my code:**

```
@Test
public void testFileUpload() {
    final File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResource("test.txt").getFile());

    assertNotNull(file);
    assertTrue(file.canRead());

    given()
        .multiPart(file)
        .expect()
        // problem here
        .body(equalsTo("This is an uploaded test file."))
      .when()
        .post("/service/file/upload");
}

@Test
public void testGetSingleUser() {
    given()
        .expect()
        .statusCode(200)
        .body(
             "email", equalTo("test@hascode.com"),
             "firstName", equalTo("Tim"),
             "lastName", equalTo("Testerman"),
             "id", equalTo("1"))
        .when()
        .`enter code here`
        .get("/service/single-user");
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you have? Give the error message.

Answer (score 9):

I assume it is the `equalTo` from the `hamcrest` library.
Can you add this import and see if it works

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
```

Comment: I wonder why eclipse is not able to auto import it.

Answer (score 1):

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

With adding above hamcrest library, Error will be resolved.
I have tried and it worked.

Comment: How is your answer different from the previous answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `equalTo` is contained in `hamcrest.Matchers.`
Hamcrest is a framework for writing matcher objects allowing 'match' rules to be defined declaratively.
`import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;`
this import will resolve your error.
Not only equalTo but even functions like `hasItems` can use after import                                                                                     `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;`

eg:

```
`import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
 import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;`

`public void testGet() {
    baseURI="https://reqres.in/api";
    given().get("/users? 
    page=2").then().statusCode(200).
    body("data[0].first_name",equalTo("Michael")).
    body("data.first_name",hasItems("Michael","Lindsay"));
    
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

Import this Line you will get the equalTo()
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

Comment: Why would you import the whole thing instead of only importing the funtion you need, as shown in the other answers?...